# How to access the Excel Based System into Different Workstation like Webhost in webdev

Tags: vba, excel

Me and my members are too confused about this kind of problem. We have a `Excel Based Guidance System` that we're developing right now we want to make the file available in all workstation or to the school guidance office workstations. The reason why we're trying to make this work is if the `student inputs their data from workstation 1` on our input form the `admin will automatically see from their workstation 2` the updates about the database of the student if there is new data inserted. This is similar in website. The admin can see the userperformances of the user within the site. We're thinking if this is possible in excel file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible in Excel.
You need to make a Excel file as database and another Excel file for Input form.

Hope this help.

Comment: Hmmm. but can we use one file only for database and input form? and just hide some worksheet if the user is a student ? because if we try to do this there's a lot of changes that we need to do.

Comment: Yes, it is possible too. But you need to share your workbook and make a userform for User Login.

Comment: is there anytutorial for this sir how to do this? or what function of the excel should i need to study to make the file accessible for the different workstation.

Comment: I can do it if you want me to do. But I think this link will help you to create user login form: https://turbofuture.com/computers/Excel-VBA-Create-A-Basic-Login-Function

Comment: Thankyou sir :) hmmm i'll make user login form first and i'll inform you the moment i already finished the user login

Comment: Ok, it would be great if you can do it by your self. Thanks.